# Circular wave superposition

Tags: waves, wavefunction, superposition

(Per title, I do mean circular wave, not radial wave.) I'm trying to learn about wave mechanics through some 3D simulations, and I've arrived at an interesting case that I can't seem to answer through google searches.

I have a global origin, around which I can render *n* wave-circles, where wave[*n*] has r=*n*. The 'circumference' is described by a standard transverse wave function:

```
double wavefunc = amplitude * sin((two_pi_L * r * theta) - (two_pi_T * t) + phase_const);

float x = (wavefunc + r) * cos(theta);
float y = 0.0f;
float z = (wavefunc + r) * sin(theta);
```

In the case that amplitude > r/2, with some added coloring specific to my question, this results in the following pattern:

[image: Circular waves crossing]

The question is, where the waves overlap (with height = 0, they are coplanar), do they superimpose? My instinct is yes, such that the new displacement is a unified curve representing the average of the waves' global displacements, as in:

[image: Circular waves interfered]

But is that the actual science? Nearly every search result I've found describes superposition as an occurrence limited to two or more waves which meet such that they share the same basis and such that the entire y displacement from the x axis is relevant to the y' displacement. In my case, the bases are parallel, and the interaction would be partial.

TL;DR: Can coplanar, adjacent wave peaks and troughs superimpose?

Comment: To me it doesn't look like [a spherical wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) of the form $Ar^{-1}\cos(\omega t \pm kr)$ at all. Please, describe in detail what you mean by "circular wave".

Comment: Each is a stable transverse wave where the textbook X axis is wrapped around to form a circle. The direction of propagation is the circumference.

Comment: not sure what you mean by coplanar .... be careful with superposition, in math you just add waves/amplitudes but in physics superposition is a temporary phenomenon, energy is never lost in the medium, waves reemerge after they temporarily cancel etc etc,  i.e. water waves only lose energy when they crash on the beach ... not in the ocean.

Comment: What does it mean for "the textbook X axis is wrapped around to form a circle"? Can you write down the formulæ for these things?

Comment: @Nolnoch Can you give some examples of waves which can travel around circle perimeter, aka circumference ? And what type of wave is that, mechanical, electromagnetic wave, etc ?